# Suspend and resume a sub-process started by QProcess in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

How can I suspend and resume a subprocess that I started as a QProcess in Qt? Is there a Qt function for that, or if not, a platform-specific one that would work on Linux?

Comment: Stopping the espeak process may or may not immediately stop sound coming out of your speakers.

Comment: I tested it on my computer (Ubuntu linux), and sound stops immediately. Why would it not stop immediately?

Comment: It depends on how espeak is implemented. If it synthesizes a large chunk of text at a time, and sends it to underlying hardware (or to another process, e.g. a sound daemon), then stopping the process will not have effect on the chunk already sent and it would play to the end.

Comment: Haven't you found any solution also for Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I'm on linux, I used the [kill()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/kill) function.

```
#include <signal.h>
...
kill(process->pid(), SIGSTOP); // suspend
kill(process->pid(), SIGCONT); // resume
```

Comment: Works perfectly... I'm using C++ Qt QProcess and this works like a charm in pausing and resuming a process...